# library tag vs. software-library tag: Which should we use?

Tags: discussion, tags

Up until 3 or 4 minutes ago there was 1 question using the [software-library] tag and 1 using the [library] tag.

Then I did a [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/708/php-ocr-library) and that changed it to 2 to 1. So which tag should be used?

Answer (score 8):

I suggest:

- **[Library-Programming]**, for things like [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) and [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/), whioh are used for programming
- **[Library-Books]** be for things like [Koha](http://www.koha.org/), [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), to do with managing physical or electronic libraries of texts
- **[Library]** tag be black-listed, as it is too unclear on this site.

---

#### Why we need **[Library-Books]** Tag:

(and why we can't let Library-programming hog it)

So far there is [one question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/476/ebook-reader-similar-to-kobo-desktop-for-ubuntu/477#477) that could have been tags this way.
That makes it over 0.5% of all questions.

If this site had have existed 3 years ago when I needed to decide on library software for our organisations library, I would have asked here (Koha, has so many disadvantages).

A few month ago, my wife wanted to catalogue our extensive home library and saw some great iOS program for it, and was trying to find a similar one for windows phone.

I think there will be *enough* **[Library-Books]** question.

If we allow Programming Libraries, which it is true there will be many many more of to use the **[Library]** Tag. Then they will swamp the eventual dozen or so questions that should be under [Library-Book], and become very hard to find.

The other option is a good tag wiki.

<sub>I don't actually feeel super strongly about this, but it might be coming off as if do</sub>

Comment: I don't think there will be many library-books question, whereas I am expecting a lot of library-programming. In that case, library could be perfectly used instead of library-programming

Comment: @Bernhard: I've updated my question with a response.

Comment: I agree that [tag:library] has too much potential for ambiguity. But I don't like the [tag:library-programming] name. Let me think of a better name.

Comment: Perhaps, Library-Framework? Library-Software is no good as it is just as ambiguous. hmmm

Comment: [tag:Library] can be an alias for programming one instead of blacklisted. That's how 99% of people will use it, I predict

Comment: @DVK no, we should enforce clarity, since some people may use library for "books library" too. I prefer not letting an ambiguous tag be synonymous of anything

Answer (score 4):

I add this answer such that the votecount makes it clear.

[software-library] should be used

Comment: Hmmph I should have thought to add this myself when I started this discussion; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about: `[*-library]`, e.g.

[java-library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java-library)[python-library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-library)

Apart from the corner case of porting code, I think you're always looking for an implementation in a specific language.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think [library] is the tag that should be used not [software-library] because:

- this site is 99% about software so saying 'software' is duplication
- If I go by the how the that  developers I know (and myself) refer to them and everywhere I have ever seen it written again it is [library] or -library not software-library