# Why beta added with software recommendations?

Tags: discussion, site-name

When I first entered SoftwareRecommendations, the thing I noticed first is the 'beta' along with the name. I also use Stackoverflow, Superuser, and Programmer. I didn't find such a thing there.

Why you people added beta to SoftwareRecommendations ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites go through 3 stages:

- Private Beta
- Public Beta
- Graduated

This site is currently in Public Beta.
This means that we are getting additional support/monitoring from Stack Exchange Community Managers, (SE employees).

On a beta site the Reputation Threshold for most privileges is a lot lower. As it is a young site, there just hasn't been enough time for enough people to get up there.

It is also a warning, that the site (or community) is still undergoing development. Some rules aren't set in stone, or are not documented. For example, [this has been decided on but never put into practice:](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/282/tag-library-vs-tag-software-library)

We will exit Public Beta after we meet certain requirements, and SE (as a company) is happy with how this is working out. You can see our progress [here on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations)

Alternatively, it might be that it is decided that this site doesn't work out, and it will be scrapped. I haven't heard of a public beta being scrapped, but it happens not infrequently to private beta sites. AI has been scraped twice now in private beta.

[Much more information can be found on this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)

Comment: [Firearms](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/164), [Economics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618), [Atheism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2732), [Startups](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243), [Healthcare IT](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6433), [Libraries](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12432), [SmugMug](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25069) - And there's a whole lot more that were closed already during the private beta.